# Rust BigInt memory allocation and performance compared to Python BigInt implementation

Tags: python, performance, memory, rust, bigint

When working with num_bigint::BigInt I have run into some performance limitations, for context I am working on https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-generate-large-prime-numbers-for-rsa-algorithm/ [full code at bottom of page].

In the nBitRand function we essentially shuffle a vector of BigInt's determined by the range:

`(2.pow(n - 1)  + 1)..(2.pow(n) - 1)`

I have made a function to calculate pow for BigInts:

```
fn big_pow(base: BigInt, exp: BigInt) -> BigInt
{
    if exp == BigInt::from_u32(0).unwrap()
    {
        return BigInt::from_u32(1).unwrap();
    }
    let mut answer = base.clone();
    let mut i = BigInt::from_u32(1).unwrap();
    while i < exp
    {
        i = i + BigInt::from_u32(1).unwrap();
        answer = answer * base.clone();
    }
    return answer;
}
```

Now here is the function for nBitRand which uses the big_pow function:

```
fn nBitRand(n: BigInt) -> BigInt
{
    let big2 = BigInt::from_u64(2).unwrap();
    let big1 = BigInt::from_u64(1).unwrap();
    let mut range: Vec<BigInt> =
        num_iter::range_inclusive
        (
            (big_pow(big2.clone(), n.clone() - big1.clone()) + big1.clone()),
            (big_pow(big2.clone(), n.clone()) - big1.clone())
        )
        .collect();
    range.shuffle(&mut rand::thread_rng());
    return range[0].clone();
}
```

When I try this function with a number n that is larger than 32 I get this panic:

`memory allocation of 137438953440 bytes failed`

Meanwhile the python implementation can do 1024 bits of n seamlessly?

Not to mention that if I do actually run this function for 32 bits of n ( in release mode or not )
it runs terribly slow and nearly crashes my PC which is running several other processes as most peoples PCs are.

Is this the same for every current BigInt implementation in rust? I would much rather use Rust than Python in general, is it expected that I should just use python for any number this big?

Comment: See https://github.com/tczajka/bigint-benchmark-rs.

Comment: Thank you I will be testing this out

Comment: It would be helpful to see full minimum viable examples of both the Rust and Python code. I can think of a few reasons Python is (surprisingly) performing better than Rust, but without code it's all speculation.

Comment: I suspect your Python code is lazily generating the large integers as needed rather than building them all up-front (whereas the Rust code you have shown is building them all at the beginning). Generally if you have equivalent Rust/Python code, I would expect the Rust to execute faster and have a lower memory usage.

Comment: As an update as soon as I use gen_bigint_range I get astoundingly better performance, my naive method of choosing a random bigint range clearly caused the memory over usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are having issues is that there are a lot of numbers between `2.pow(n - 1)` and `2^pow(n)`, and your rust code is trying to hold all of them in memory at once. Just trying to hold the numbers between `2^31` and `2^32` in memory all at once will likely require a few tens of gigabytes of ram, which is evidently more than your computer can handle.

The correct way to handle this is to use something like the [`gen_bigint`](https://docs.rs/num/0.4.0/num/bigint/trait.RandBigInt.html#tymethod.gen_bigint) which handles this elegantly:

```
use rand::prelude::*;
use num::bigint::RandBigInt;
fn main(){
    println!("{}", thread_rng().gen_bigint(1024));
}
```

(no playground link because it requires activating the `rand` feature)

sample output:

```
-120678186469168050141127714278465650797509809181209645055716269782732917216510450905974158776294027244037250792198062938087103374539558073937169391547408613028913574776101294537137332842677479099864132223045958106561504255177421361770704902635830935432132237493695901107602818879400859307921127547090428474495
```

Comment: Also see [num_bigint::RandBigInt::gen_bigint_range](https://docs.rs/num-bigint/0.4.3/num_bigint/trait.RandBigInt.html#tymethod.gen_bigint_range)

Comment: Thank you so much and as a reference to the python code, it is at the very bottom of the page here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-generate-large-prime-numbers-for-rsa-algorithm/ you can also run the example on that page if you sign in.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone wants to use this, add `use num_bigint::RandBigInt;` to your use directives.

Also in `cargo.toml` enable rand feature in `bigint` as such:

```
num-bigint = {version = "0.4.3", features = ["rand"] }
```

If you are working with `num_bigint` as I am.

Use the function like this:

```
gen_bigint_range(&mut rand::thread_rng(), &lowerbound.clone(), &higherbound.clone());
```

Docs: https://docs.rs/num-bigint/0.4.3/num_bigint/trait.RandBigInt.html#tymethod.gen_bigint_range

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/75022843/4) to the question [Questions about Rust BigInt memory allocation and performance compared to Python BigInt implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75022843/questions-about-rust-bigint-memory-allocation-and-performance-compared-to-python) by the OP [Poseidon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16402314/poseidon) under CC BY-SA 4.0.</sub>